# Running untrusted application on Wine

Tags: linux, wine, sandbox

I want to play some offline Windows game on GNU/Linux, so I think I should use Wine.

This game does not have available source code so I don't trust it as there were spyware cases already (like Blizzard's Warden).

How do I run that game? Should I use firejail or something like that? How?

Comment: It is called "wine prefix" where program save their file. Create temporary wine prefix, run the program with that path, delete that path after use.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, I think there must be some sandbox. The game might contain malware which steals or destroys files.

Comment: The best sandbox is a VM...

Comment: xenoid: or a chroot env :) :) :)

Comment: @Owl, IIRC it is possible to escape chroot.

Comment: No name Anonymous: oh wow, it seems you can. In fact there are many ways. Interesting - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wine does not provide any sandboxing.  Even the Wine prefix mentioned in comments is only a very limited sandbox: it keeps a well-behaved Windows program from interacting with other well-behaved Windows programs in certain ways, such as through shared registry entries.

If you don't trust the software, use a true sandbox such as a virtual machine.

Comment: What about Wine in firejail, with --private for example?

Comment: @NonameAnonymous, I'm not familiar with the inner workings of firejail, but it appears to be a blacklist-based sandbox: it permits access to everything except specific disallowed resources.  `firejail --private` might be sufficient, particularly if the malware isn't designed to run on Linux, but I'd prefer something whitelist-based.

Comment: As an example of the problem with blacklisting, Firejail's compiler blacklist includes compilers for C, C++, Go, Java, and Rust, but not Fortran or Pascal.  The interpreters blacklist blocks `python2` and `python3`, but if you've got an older install that just calls it `python`, that's not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

[sandwine](https://github.com/hartwork/sandwine) may be an option for a Wine sandbox. The main readme has a section on its threat model.